# SVG image can not be used for Flutter

Tags: flutter, svg

I want to use SVG icon for flutter android app. This image is downloaded from figma design file and can be opened with browser but can not used in flutter android app. I used flutter_svg package and yaml file path is correct. When I load this SVG icon on app, only show white rectangle.

I found previous similar answer, they said using AI app can fix SVG format to use in flutter app. But I don't have AI app on my computer. Is there any website or another way to fix and use SVG image.

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is in your SVG file.

Comment: 99% percent sure it's related to some id names (used for symbols, gradients, filters etc). Quite common are issues caused by ids containing characters like colons ":". Admittedly – Not per se standard incompliant ... but not selectable via js/css. Please provide a sample of your svg output.

Comment: @herrstrietzel I can't provide svg output, cause this output exceed the maximum body letter limitation of stackoverflow asking section.

Comment: You could add your svg to a jsfiddle or codepen and add the link here. You might also try to run your svg through SVGOMG optimizer, since it can correct some minor file issues

Comment: SVGOMG for chrome extension is useful. Please follow below link to check my SVG format.

https://codepen.io/leoLinux/pen/BawKqre

Comment: Id and base64 encoding seems to be OK. Next ideas: the base64 encoded png has issues. I've also switched the order of some elements/defs.
Could you try this version? [edited svg](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/vYeKEVm)

Comment: [edited svg](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/vYeKEVm) don't also work. And I don't mess with this and use another svg. thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

```
use flutter_svg package from pub.dev

final String assetName = 'assets/image.svg';
final Widget svg = SvgPicture.asset(
  assetName,
  semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo'
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read my question careful. I said I used flutter_svg package and any other SVG files for my project can be used. But only this file can't loaded. So I ask 'How to fix the SVG file to correct format.' Thanks for answer.